# php7 fsockopen timout with basic php

Tags: php, fsockopen

Running on nginx, phpfpm 7.2. My code was working great on phpfpm 5 but updated to 7 and now I'm getting timeout issues.

I've tried setting timeouts in php.ini and keep getting timeout errors. The code is just simple basic:

```
$fsock = fsockopen('1.1.1.1', 22, $errno, $errstr); 
echo $errstr;
```

I can connect to the server fine via terminal.

Comment: The fact that it's an issue even when `fsockopen` is used makes me think that any mention of phpseclib is a distraction. ie. the people who monitor the fsockopen tag on SO may ignore this question because the first thing they see is a discussion of phpseclib and they don't know phpseclib so they might tune out before they see that's an issue ultimately with `fsockopen`.

Comment: thank you sir, I've already had a discussion on phpseclib github, they were unable to help and told me to come here.

Comment: I've edited your post. Over half your post was about phpseclib when phpseclib ultimately has nothing to do with the issues you're having. As such the people who know about `fsockopen` are liable to not to respond to your post. They'd see you talking about phpseclib and prob just ignore everything else after that.